# Displaying a website in a website?

Tags: java, php, html, proxy

What I need to do is this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
```

But the constraint is, I want my website to fetch a requested website and display it in
frame. That is, the clients browser must only have a connection with my web server. My website
in turn will fetch requested url's and display them to the client.

The only way I have thought I could do this is perhaps passing the url to an application that in turn downloads the page and then redirects the clients browser to the page (now stored locally on my web server). The problem is however that this would only work with rather boring and static sites, I require the website in the website do be fully functioning, ie streaming video, secure connections...

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: sounds like you want a proxy server which embeds the result in your page. which I believe is what http://anonymouse.org/ does.

Comment: If only there were some way to set the source of a frame to some other web site address

Comment: @1800, well, he said the client can *only* connect to him. So he'd have to proxy the other sites.

Comment: but if I proxy the sites clients be able to log into other websites through my website?

Comment: @Dunkman, because I need the sites it displays not to be restrained in any way, I need data comming in and out. Someone before suggested using a reverse proxy, I have not read up much yet, but so far I think it looks like it could work, thanks to who ever that was...

Comment: Your only real option involves having the clients go through you as a proxy.  Unfortunately, if you want to modify the traffic coming in and out you not only have to break the security of any connections, but you most likely are going to break any AJAX content trying to go through you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to break it to you, but I don't think there's a foolproof way to do this. What you're trying to do is make a proxy, and there's several ways to do it, but either way you won't be able to take things like Flash and JavaScript into account. I've used a lot of different proxies to get around the filter at my school and not one of them has been 100% effective. In fact, I don't think a single one has been able to load the music player on either PureVolume or MySpace.

If you still want to give it a try, read this article: [Using Apache As A Proxy Server](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Administration/Using-Apache-As-A-Proxy-Server/)

Answer (score 3):

If one of your requirements is

> ... secure connections

that is not possible at all. By definition a secure end-to-end connections cannot go thru a proxy (see [Man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack))

Comment: NAT defies that definition. I need to aswell

Comment: NAT blindly relays traffic - it can't see the contents of the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, to who ever mentioned it and then deleted their answer, thanks.

Making use of a reverse proxy could do this, http://docsrv.sco.com/INT_Proxy/revpxy.htm shows some ways in which a reverse proxy may be used.

Paramesh Gunasekaran wrote a tutorial on creating your own reverse proxy with code supplied.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/reverseproxy.aspx